# c - Segmentation fault when using global struct variable

Tags: c, function, struct, header, global

This is in a program meant to work with ppm image files.

I'm getting a segmentation fault when trying to read an image from a file and assigning that image to my global struct image.

These are the relevant parts of my ppmIO.c file:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <ppmIO.h>

struct Image *instance;

void ImageRead(char *filename)
{
  printf("hi 0!");
  int width, height, num, size;
  //unsigned char *p;

  //Image *image = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
  FILE  *fp    = fopen(filename, "r");

  //if (!image) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");
  if (!fp)    die("cannot open file for reading");

  readPPMHeader(fp, &width, &height);


  size = width * height * 3;
  printf("hi!");
  //instance->data   = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);
  printf("hi 2!");
  instance->width  = width;
  printf("hi 3!");
  instance->height = height;
  printf("hi 4!");

  if (!instance->data) die("cannot allocate memory for new image");

  num = fread((void *) instance->data, 1, (size_t) size, fp);

  if (num != size) die("cannot read image data from file");


  fclose(fp);

}
```

This is my ppmIO.h file:

```
#ifndef PPMIO_H
#define PPMIO_H

struct Image
{
  int width;
  int height;
  unsigned char *data;
};

extern struct Image *instance;

//extern Image *ImageCreate(int width, int height);
//extern void ImageClear(struct Image *image, unsigned char red, unsigned char green, unsigned char blue);
extern void ImageRead(char *filename);
extern void ImageWrite(char *filename);

extern void ImageSetPixel(int x, int y, int chan, unsigned char val);
extern unsigned char ImageGetPixel(int x, int y, int chan);

#endif /* PPMIO_H */
```

And this is the segmentation fault that GDB reports:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400fff in ImageRead (filename=0x7fffffffdc32 "nika.ppm")
    at ppmIO.c:126
126   instance->width  = width;
```

I think there is a problem with how I'm trying to use the `Image *instance`... but I really have no real clue what is causing this mess. :(

Comment: You never allocate any memory for `instance`.  Before you try and set the width, do: `instance = malloc(sizeof *instance);`

Comment: @Tibrogargan When I try to allocate memory for instance like this: `struct Image *instance = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));`
I get an error and the code doesn't compile. The error: `ppmIO.c:14:27: error: ‘Image’ undeclared here (not in a function)
 struct Image *instance = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
                           ^
ppmIO.c:14:34: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
 struct Image *instance = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));`

Comment: Yes, "Image" does not exist, you want `struct Image` or add a typedef.  And don't cast the return value of malloc.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks! But when I do this: `struct Image *instance = (struct Image *) malloc(sizeof(struct Image));` I get the error: `ppmIO.c:14:26: error: initializer element is not constant
 struct Image *instance = (struct Image *) malloc(sizeof(struct Image));
`

Comment: Don't try and initialize the value of instance when you declare it, it's a limitation of the language (for static initializers).  Leave the declaration alone and just assign it some memory before you use it.  And don't cast the return value of malloc

Comment: @Tibrogargan So, I did this: `struct Image *instance;
instance = (struct Image *) malloc(sizeof(struct Image));` 
But I still get an error: `ppmIO.c:15:1: error: conflicting types for ‘instance’
ppmIO.c:14:15: note: previous declaration of ‘instance’ was here
 struct Image *instance;`

Comment: No offense, but If you're not going to follow directions why ask the question?  Just before you try and set the width do `instance = malloc(sizeof *instance);`.  Nothing else.  It's already declared, you don't need to declare it again.  And [don't cast the return value of malloc](/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @Tibrogargan My bad! I misread your suggestion. Doing what you said just now works well!! Thanks again!

Comment: @Tibrogargan I'm now getting a related error... not sure why. `Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040104b in ImageRead (filename=0x7fffffffdc32 "nika.ppm")
    at ppmIO.c:124
124   instance->data   = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);
`

Comment: The code you have in this question has that line commented out, so it's pretty much a completely different question.

Comment: Oh, my bad again... I un-commented it in my copy... not here though. Do you recommend posting a different question for this? And my apologies for my noobishness.. I'm very new to all of this.

Comment: From looking at the current code I suspect you're trying to use `instance->data` before you allocate any memory for `instance` itself (exactly the same issue you had trying to set the width).  Don't fall into the error of depending on the kindness of strangers, try and work it out yourself first.

Comment: @Tibrogargan Thanks again! I did allocate memory to instance, but after `instance->data = (unsigned char *) malloc(size);`... I feel I'm hurrying into fixing my code right now, I will take some time and try to work on it before asking more questions.Thanks a lot! Indeed very kind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting this error as you have not allocated any memory for `instance`. Before you try and use any member of instance (i.e. `width` or `data`) you must allocate memory (from inside a function), i.e:

```
instance = malloc(sizeof *instance);
```

You should not cast the return value of instance (See: [this](/a/605858/2487517)), and there is no need to specify the type since the compiler already knows.  You can't allocate the memory when you declare the variable as static initializations must be to constant values (See: [this](/a/3025106/2487517)) (the return value of a function is not constant).

You will also need to allocate memory for the `instance->data` part of the structure, based on the size you read from the file.